# Meeting Organizer in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I've recently had a problem with my pc so I've made a pst copy and started a new Windows installation.

I've upgraded to office 2010 but when I import the old pst all my meetings say that I'm not the organizer and that I should contact .

Anyone knows a way to "force" the organizer of the already scheduled options to be me?